# Syntax error with a tag array Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript, syntax, input, tags, slider

If I have this slider with an input that have to have an array as id tag , how can I call the tag on the script where I initialize and build the slider? This code works if the input not is an array but I need that "amount" be an array.

```
/////////////////////SLIDER !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

< !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   < script>

    var valueslider= "<?= $AnswerValue ?>";
    var mysliderdef= valueslider.split(";");
          var len = mysliderdef.length-1;
                    var i =0;
                        var qid="<?= $QuestionID ?>";
                    var answerid="<?= $AnswerID?>";
                    **$( "#amount"+qid).**val( mysliderdef[0]);//<-My tag name problem

                    $( "#slider" ).slider({ 
                    min: 1,
                    max: mysliderdef.length,                                        
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {

                    **$( "#amount"+qid).**val( mysliderdef[ui.value-1]); //<- My tag name problem                       
                                            }//end slide event
                                            });//end slider ini method builder


                });// end JavaScript document function  

< /script>


    <!--SLIDER-->   
        <?php if($row_questionset['Constructor']=="Slider"){?>
```

< input type="text" **id="amount< ?= $row_Answer['QuestionIDFK'];? >[]"** name="amount[]" />

```
    < div id="slider" name="<?php echo $row_Answer['AnswerValue']; ?>" >< /div>
                                            <?php }  ?>     

                                            <?php }  ?> 
                        <!--/SLIDER-->
```

I tried with

```
$( "#amount"+qid+[]).val( mysliderdef[ui.value-1]); 

$( "#amount"+qid[]).val( mysliderdef[ui.value-1]); 

 var qid="<?= $QuestionID ?>"[];
$( "#amount"+qid).val( mysliderdef[ui.value-1]);
```

How do I have to write this syntax?

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your post what the issue is - can you clarify your problem definition and remove some of the code that is not related to the problem?

Comment: i did the changes for improve my question

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix JavaScript and PHP, you will go nuts with that - never being sure which part of the logic is executed when.

Your problem is that you echo many paragraphs and slider divs in a loop. Notice that the ids you give elements need to be unique in the whole document. You have correctly amended the input ids with a counter value: `id="amount<?= $row_Answer['QuestionIDFK'];?>[]"` (omit the `[]`, btw), but did not for the `id="slider"`. Use the question id there, too.

Use similiar for the `answervalue` now. Do not output question- and answer-ids directly in the middle of the JS code, but only once in a JSON config object (use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)). This config object should contain all the necessary values, ordered by questionid. Loop over that object with [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and init the slider (the one with the unique id) with the respective values.

Comment: ok, i added the id for the sliders  too , but i need that amount be an array because i want save multiple answer values with multiple sliders for each one question . If i only wanted one answervalue i wouldn't have this problem. Without [] everything go right , but i need that the tag id be id="id="amount< ?= $row_Answer['QuestionIDFK'];? >[]" .My problem is when i call this tag in the script and is only for  this : []

Comment: Why do you need the brackets there? I can understand it in the `name` attribute, but not for the id - before HTML5, such an id would be even invalid.

Comment: If you really need to select an element with that id, go for `$(document.getElementById("amount"+idfk+"[]"))`